# CMake post build step: copy multiple files dependent on visual studio configuration

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, cmake

I'm trying to write a `CMakeLists.txt` which copies as a post build event required `dlls` from external libraries to the folder in which the executable is located after building. The OS I'm working on is Win7 and VS2010.

There a quite a lot of external libraries, so I do not want to list them individually within the `CMakeLists.txt`. My current solution is to use file globbing and create a post build event for each library:

```
FILE(GLOB files "${LIBRARY_DIR}/lib/$(ConfigurationName)/*dll")
MESSAGE("FILE LIST IS: ${files}")
FOREACH(file ${files})
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
        TARGET mylib
        POST_BUILD
        COMMENT "Copying dll ${file}..."
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${file} "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/$(ConfigurationName)/"
    )
ENDFOREACH()
```

Basically, the code snipped above works file if I replace `$(ConfigurationName)` with `Release` or `Debug`. However, I'd like to take the libraries from the corresponding directory dependent on Release or Debug build mode. In the code snipped above, `$(ConfigurationName)` does not get substituted by the visual studio build mode. I guess this is due to that this is a VS2010 variable which isn't known at cmake generation time).

Does somebody have a smart idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Isn't it just `$(Configuration)` and not `$(ConfigurationName)`?

Answer (score 1):

`ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND` understands generator expressions, so you would be able to use `$<CONFIG>` rather than `$(Configuration)` or `$(ConfigurationName)` there. For the `FILE` command, however, this won't work. More importantly though, the file globbing approach isn't going to work for the first time you build your project if those DLL's are built as part of the same project, since none of the DLL's would be there when you first run CMake in such an arrangement.

You may want to look into [BundleUtilities](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/BundleUtilities.html) as a more robust way to solve your problem. Despite its name, it supports all platforms, not just Mac. You would need to invoke the `fixup_bundle` command as a post-build or install step to achieve what you describe. There are a few variations of this approach already described online (e.g. [here](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-August/045706.html) and [here](https://cmake.org/Wiki/BundleUtilitiesExample)).
You can also have a look at the source for the `DeployQt4.cmake` file which should be included in the `Modules` subdirectory of your CMake installation for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose you have `_TARGET_NAME` filled with your your project name, and `ADDITIONAL_DLL_PATH` with a list of folders containing external dlls, Then the following code will copy any external dependencies found using `dumpbin` on windows.

```cmake
foreach(CONF_TYPE ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES})
 string(TOUPPER ${CONF_TYPE} CONF_TYPE_U)
 get_property(TARGET_LOCATION_${CONF_TYPE_U} TARGET ${_TARGET_NAME} PROPERTY LOCATION_${CONF_TYPE_U})
 get_filename_component(TARGE_DIR ${TARGET_LOCATION_${CONF_TYPE_U}} PATH)
 install(CODE "
   if (\"\${BUILD_TYPE}\" STREQUAL \"${CONF_TYPE}\")
     include(BundleUtilities)
     fixup_bundle(\"${TARGET_LOCATION_${CONF_TYPE_U}}\" \"\" \"${ADDITIONAL_DLL_PATH}\")
  endif()"
  COMPONENT Runtime)
endforeach()
```

There are downsides to this solution though, Like the need to build `INSTALL` target whenever you need to copy those files (which might not be many times), and not detecting delay loaded dlls.